# Behavior of before_save with equals operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my model, I use `before_save` to capitalize the first letter of the title. I tried using variants of something like

`before_save { self.title[0].upcase! }` which do not affect the title at all.

Only when I use the equals operator is there any effect on the title at all.

`before_save { self.title = self.title.sub(/\S/, &:upcase) }`

Is there any particular reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an attribute accessor in your model for `title[0]`. You'll have one for `title`. So making a change to `title[0]` won't affect `title`. You need to understand that your code operates on a character in a string, not on the string itself.

`before_save { self.title.capitalize! }` might work.